# Optimize code multiple if else statements

Tags: c

I have a piece of code that looks pretty ugly. I'm trying to compare a single 12 bit data in hex to see if it is any of 0xff8 to 0xfff. The code returns true if it fits any of the numbers in the said range. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
/******************************************************************/
/* summary: Checks if the cluster is the last cluster in a file.  */
/* return: returns 1 if true and 0 if false                       */
/******************************************************************/
int lastCluster(unsigned int cluster){
    /*Compares the values of the cluster. The cluster is the last cluster in a
    file if the cluster has a value of 0xff8-0xfff.*/
    if(cluster == 0xff8){
       return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xff9){
        return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xffa){
        return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xffb){
        return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xffc){
        return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xffd){
        return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xffe){
        return (1);
    }
    else if(cluster == 0xfff){
        return (1);
    }
    else{
       return (0);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine these into a single test

```
if (cluster>=0xff8 && cluster<=0xfff)
    return 1;
return 0;
```